# How to detect if an element is "Stale" in Geb?

Tags: groovy, webdriver, geb

I'm trying to detect if a module has gone "stale" in Geb. That is, if using will throw:
**`org.openqa.selenium.StaleElementReferenceException`**

The below code seems to work, but I feel like its excessively hacky (I'm just calling any arbitrary method on `module` (`toString()` seemed like a decent choice) and checking if it throws the stale element exception.

```
static boolean isStale(Module module)
{
    boolean isStale = false
    try {
        module.toString() // arbitrary method call
    } catch (StaleElementReferenceException e) {
        isStale = true
    }
    return isStale
}
```

Is there a cleaner way to do this?

Comment: I was going through this link: http://darrellgrainger.blogspot.ca/2012/06/staleelementexception.html that is almost similar with your approach. I found this link from another question of SO. Can you please tell me why it's not clean enough?

Comment: @S.M.AlMamun I've come to the conclusion that it is in fact the best way. I was just hoping that there might be a cleaner way b/c I don't like to resort to using Exceptions for controlling the flow of my code. They should be "exceptional" circumstances, but this is expected for what I'm using it for. If you'd like to add a response confirming that it seems to be the only approach, I'll give you a check-mark.

Comment: haha, my little knowledge says that it is the best approach. I wish Peter would come here and drop another comment!

Comment: Can you please explain why you need to know if a module base element is stale? What is your use case? I'm pretty sure that there is a better way to solve your problem then by doing this. Especially because it uses Exceptions for controlling flow as you have already mentioned.

Comment: @erdi a very reasonable question. I'm actually doing it in order to check if the page has changed. `at` checkers won't work, because these pages are somewhat arbitrary, so cannot separate `Page` objects. There probably is a better way, and I'd be open to suggestions.

Answer (score 1):

If you are trying to detect page changes, however arbitrary those pages are then I would probably tackle it the other way around - detecting the new content and not the stale content. First, you have to find something (an element or a state of an element) that you can use in your at checker to detect that the new page has "loaded". Then you would execute the page changing action and wrap an at checker verification inside of a `waitFor {}` call. This should be more reliable than your current approach, especially because Geb doesn't cache any content elements by default.